# Big Sur vs Ventura (macOS 11 vs 13) difference in memory usage?

Tags: memory, big-sur, ventura

I have an M1 mac, and I am thinking of downgrading to Big Sur. It came with Ventura. I notice it uses 4GB after starting it up, without opening any apps, without hardly any background items (other than battery and Rectangle). Once I use it for a while, it shows almost 5GB when I close all the apps.

I couldn't find anywhere online that shows the difference in how much RAM the different versions of macOS use. Meaning, how much RAM does it use when you turn it on without opening any apps or adding any background items.

EDIT:

I'm not sure what happened. But I tested it again. After having some applications open and then closing them, it's now showing 3.75GB of RAM used.

Comment: Exactly which Mac is it? Unless the Mac is 2 years older than Ventura, you will not be able to install Big Sur. Macs will not run any OS older than themselves, with very few exceptions. Big Sur is also no longer supported & will not receive even security updates.

Comment: it's an M1 macbook. The same hardware as the 2020 version, but manufactured in 2022.

Comment: Does it have the same memory usage after booting it in Safe Mode? And approximately what percentage of the hard drive/SSD is free space?

Comment: The link below might help. To me it suggests that the memory used by the base system is the Wired Memory figure, while the Memory Used figure is the total used memory figure which also includes the memory taken up by Cached Files. So that suggests to me that subtracting Cached Files from Memory Used may be a better figure for the kind of memory usage I think you’re talking about. Somebody please correct me if I’m wrong. https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/activity-monitor/actmntr1004/10.14/mac/13.0

Comment: No, cached files are not part of the memory used figure. Just wired memory (the kernel) and app memory (the processes that make up the "operating system" that are automatically stared by it), including compressed app memory.

Comment: For comparison my memory used in Safe Mode on Sonoma on M1 MacBook Air was ~6.6GB

Comment: Are you seeing high Memory Pressure? Is anything running apparently slower? Using more RAM may not be a problem -- in fact, it may bring performance improvements. I wouldn't downgrade just because of different numbers. And what about upgrading to Sonoma, rather than downgrading?